Check that a string is a palindrome using Cython
I am trying to check if a string is a palindrome in cython. Here is the code I am using:
cpdef bint check_palindrome(
    str word,
):
    cdef:
        int N = len(word)
        int i

    for i in range(N // 2 + 1):
        if word[i] != word[N-i-1]:
            return 0

    return 1

How can I make it more efficient? I suspect that the len() function is not cythonic, however I am more concerned about the check if word[i] != word[N-i-1] which gets repeated in a loop. How could it be improved? I would be checking a large number of very long (10000+ character-long) strings.

Seems pretty optimal to me unless you want to try to vectorize. What's the concern about the if word[i] != word[N-i-1] check specifically?

When I run the script through cython -a <filename>.pyx, that line is bright yellow-colored, which indicates it might be more efficient if done using a C-based alternative.

I don't know anything about cython, but if word[i] != word[N-i-1] looks about as fast as you can get in C (barring vectorization), just offsets into an array (string).

This innocently-looking code hides a lot. Are your strings ASCII (or other single-byte) encoding, or do you need to support multi-bytes encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, ...)? How is it called from python later?

If you can restrict this to ASCII, then cpdef bint check_palindrome(bytes word), then cdef char* c_word = word and then indexing into c_word should be closer to c-native iteration (likely nothing yellow in the loop). Also int N = len(word) and int i should be Py_ssize_t, though this won't have any performance impact. Mandatory reading: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/strings.html

The strings are digits only, e.g. "12345" for False and "12321" for True.

I have the freedom of converting the number to a string or to a bytes string.

already fast
The word[i] != word[N - i - 1] test looks Just Fine,
you won't go much faster than that in any language.
(Though I do wish you would
name
it lowercase n.)
I assume the len(word) operation happens in \$O(1)\$ constant time.
Please ensure that word is a (readonly) byte array
when it's passed in, so it is compact and we needn't worry
about unicode details.
BLAS
You might take it out of the hands of cython,
and let numpy worry about reversing bytes and
worry about comparisons.
If you want to take advantage of vectorized instructions,
"make it numpy's problem!" is the lowest effort
path to accomplishing that.
Notice that conversion to bytes, or conversion to a numpy
array,
will be a \$O(N)\$ linear operation.
So the possible speedups are pretty meager.
What could be winning is if you get to translate
to a new representation once and then re-use that datastructure
many times. Also, you might be using pyarrow's Parquet
file format to map a file into memory.
In that case it might happen that you never even fault
the middle page, upon finding a mismatch in pages near the beginning.
alignment
The OP code is simple enough that it gives an -O3 C compiler
an opportunity to use vector instructions for fetching and
comparisons. We might see better code generated if the
compiler can easily prove some convenient alignment.
Rely on godbolt and your stopwatch
to verify that any proposed edit actually does some good.
We might even wish to have a variable number of bytes
in the middle, to ensure that the end has a nice alignment.
cache friendly
You didn't mention what sort of distribution your mismatches follow,
nor whether you typically see a 1% or a 99% palindrome rate.
In the 99% case, there's little to be done, since you necessarily
have to examine each and every byte.
But in the 1% case, we care about where we detect a mismatch.
If there's typically a mismatch near {front, back},
then OP code is already optimal.
If for many of the False results we can find
a mismatch near the middle, then focus on that.
(Even if front vs middle is similar frequencies, still focus on middle.)
We can test from the middle outward just as easily
as the current testing from the ends inward.
But if the mismatch is very near the middle,
then we can win after dragging one cache line
in from L3 or main memory, instead of two.
Cache lines are smallish.
Virtual memory pages are bigger than a kilobyte.
As mentioned above, demand faulting from e.g. Parquet
could let you declare "not a palindrome!" without
even having the bulk of the string loaded into RAM.
N threads
Actually, in the 99% case you could burn more cores.
Divide the string into sub-segments that are delegated
to individual threads.
We can do the OP comparison in each thread.
Or we can choose to optimistically compute
hash of input segment in just one direction,
and do a quick comparison of segment hashes
to verify that yes, it is a palindrome.
Given that you have a large number of input strings,
so the metric of interest is throughput rather than latency,
there's probably little reason to adopt such an approach.
Better to parallelize across input strings,
assigning each one to a particular thread.
input distribution
It might be the case that non-palindromes often start
with particular prefixes.
Compute hashes of such prefixes and store them in a dict,
along with offset of probable mismatch.
Use that as a "fast path" for quickly demonstrating
that the input is definitely not a palindrome.
Or, almost the same thing, use a probabilistic datastructure
like a Bloom filter
to quickly identify such inputs.

In Python, how do I go about converting an int to a readonly byte array? Is there anything more efficient than x = 12321; list(str(x).encode("UTF-8"))? The second operation alone takes as much time as my test for palindromicity.
